# How to Convert OpenCL code from FP32 to FP16?

Tags: gpu, opencl, amd-gpu, half-precision-float

Is there a way to automatically convert a code that has been written to do FP32 calculations on a FP32 GPU, so it can do always FP16 calculations instead of FP32?

What I'm trying to achieve is to run a code for an old GPU (that doesn't support HALF Type), to run on a newer GPU that does - but without going through the code myself.

If not possible, please show me what documentations I should read to do it myself.

(New GPU is Radeon Vega Frontier, driver is ROCm 1.9.1, OS is Ubuntu 18.04)
(the code is extensive and composed by different modules. So I won't be posting it here, unless asked to)

Comment: The YOLO approach is a replace-all of "float" with "half", but I suspect that might not be 100% foolproof.

Comment: Not many float types in the code really, many int tho, I've tried to change them all to short... But again, not clean and errors came along... So I need to redo the whole code...

Comment: If there isn't much float maths, hardware FP16 support is going to have pretty limited effect. For optimising integer code, going through all uint/uint and int/int multiplications and checking if it's safe to replace them with [`mul24`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/mul24.html) or even [`mad24`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/mad24.html) calls can make a big difference. I'm not sure how AMD hardware performs on short multiplications versus mul24, they may or may not be even faster.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no standard flag to say "treat float as half". You have to change `float` to `half`. Also, your device must support fp16 calculations (many don't, just fp16 *storage* that converts to/from fp32 when you load/store). The `cl_khr_fp16` extension adds support for half scalar and vector types as built-in types that can be used for arithmetic operations. You'll need a `#pragma` in any kernels that use it.

Comment: "your device must support fp16 calculations (many don't, just fp16 storage that converts to/from fp32 when you load/store)." that's what I'm saying, it does support something called RPM Rapid Packed Math, that is 16bit calculations, when input types are 16bit in size...

Comment: "cl_khr_fp16 extension adds support for half scalar and vector types as built-in types that can be used for arithmetic operations" I know that, it's already there... Made no difference what so ever...